# How to set fix time minute and second with current hour in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I want to fetch data between fix time interval.

example :(This is working in mysql and I want it in oracle)

Mysql

```
 $ReportStartDate = "DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')"
 $ReportEndDate   = "DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR),'%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59')";
```

This is working fine in mysql.How it is possible in oracle..??

Comment: You could use `BETWEEN` to compare. In SQL you would put it in the predicate, in PL/SQL, you can directly do between two variables. See my answer.

Comment: The problem is not of beetwen  but Probleme is of date format . I can't set the date formate such like ''%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00' in oracle which I can in Mysql

Comment: Can you show a sample date value, show the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without back and forth converting of `DATE` and string.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH') + INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE TO SECOND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wernfired. It's Really Helpful.Works perfect as I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want the values in character datatype in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` format and the interval has to be of last hour.
`NOW()` in Oracle is represented by `SYSDATE` function. `DATE_SUB` can be replace by direct subtraction of one hour.

```
$ReportStartDate = "to_char(trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'HH'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
$ReportEndDate   = "to_char(trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'HH') + (3599/3600)/24, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
```

Update: You can replace `sysdate` with any date you want.

Answer (score 0):

> $ReportStartDate = "DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')"
>
> $ReportEndDate   = "DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR),'%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59')";

You could convert it as:

```
$ReportStartDate = to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')||':00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
$ReportEndDate   = to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')||':59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

You could use **TO_DATE** with proper **FORMAT MODEL**. And use **BETWEEN** to filter the rows.

For example, I want to fetch all the employees hired between a time period:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT empno,
  2    hiredate
  3  FROM EMP
  4  WHERE HIREDATE BETWEEN
  5  TO_DATE('01-apr-1981 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  6  AND
  7  TO_DATE('01-dec-1981 23:59:59','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  8  /

     EMPNO HIREDATE
---------- --------------------
      7566 02-apr-1981 00:00:00
      7654 28-sep-1981 00:00:00
      7698 01-may-1981 00:00:00
      7782 09-jun-1981 00:00:00
      7839 17-nov-1981 00:00:00
      7844 08-sep-1981 00:00:00

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**UPDATE** OP wants the hour value should be from sysdate, however, minutes and seconds should be `00:00`.

You could extract the hours, and append `00:00` as minutes and seconds value:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') currentdate,
  2  to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')||':00:00' dt
  3  FROM dual;

CURRENTDATE          DT
-------------------- --------------------
20-feb-2015 12:19:39 20-feb-2015 12:00:00

SQL>
```

To use the value in any DATETIME operations, convert it to DATE using **TO_DATE**:

`to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')||':00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: I want to use current date function because any date might be come its not fix.... 
eg..
TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: For current date, use `SYSDATE`.

Comment: What is if sysdate is changed...I will get wrong data ??

Comment: Do you want a fixed date in the comparison or do you want the query to take current date everytime it runs?

Comment: minute should start with 00:00 with current date and hour.I want to know syntax of it

Comment: I want current  time every time  it runs but minute and hour of time should be start with 00:00. I have given format  of mysql . I want same in Oracle